# C , XPMEM and locks

Tags: c, locking

I'm trying to share a portion of the virtual memory between different processes using XPMEM.
This segment of memory contains a shared data structure and I would like to use a lock to order accesses to it.

Can I use already existing locks provided in C that avoids to busy wait on a single variable?

If not, what kind of lock should I implement to reduce the impact of the cache ping pong?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will probably have to implement your own locks as existing locks (pthread mutex) probably won't work (the same reason posix semaphores and pthread condition variables won't work). The limitation comes from how XPMEM maps pages from one application into another. The mapping is done by page frame number (PFN) only meaning there are no user pages on the side that called xpmem_attach on the memory region. This causes problems for any code that calls futex_wake because it relies on get_user_pages_fast returning page info. If a page does not exist (as is the case with a memory segment returned by xpmem_attach) futex_wake will return EFAULT and not wake any thread waiting on the memory region.

I am trying to figure out if there is a way to work around this issue.

Comment: Actually I seen only simple implementation of locks, and I was not aware of that problem. I was only sure that I cannot trust any library that targets threads since the mapping on the same shared object can be at different addresses in different processes. So as soon as a library refer something with a pointer it should not work. Am I right? The only solution seems to be write from scratch locks (or lock-free data structures)

Comment: You are correct that any library required to follow pointers will not work. So, any locking mechanism that does not require following pointers or waking using futex() will work fine. This includes using atomic operations + busy wait. If you want to see an example of a lock-free structure in an xpmem segment take a look at https://github.com/open-mpi/ompi/blob/master/opal/mca/btl/vader.

Comment: @NathanHjelm Is there a simpler example using XPMEM, it would be very useful.